SSL_CTX_set_keylog_callback not invoked for handshake failure scenario for TLS1.3
I have set SSL_CTX_set_keylog_callback(ctx, KeyLogCBFunction); to get the Keys in each step of my TLS 1.3 handshake and finally to decrypt the pcap using wireshark so far.
Unfortunately, in one of the scenarios, i'm getting the bellow error after client hello and server hello.
callback:3568 client(fd=0x400):   >>> TLS 1.3(0x304)  Alert [length 0002], fatal illegal_parameter  RA:0x7ffff6afeae8
callback:3204 SSL alert write(fd=0x400):fatal:illegal parameter
callback:3215 SSL_connect(fd=0x400): -1 return value during error  RA:0x7ffff6b36691
handshake:143 SSL_connect returned ret=-1
handshake:201 SSL_connect error (-1) for fd=0x400, ssl_err=1, errno=0()
handshake:211 SSL_connect error (-1) for fd=0x400, ssl_err=1, errno=0()
ssl_internal_errors:29 handshake
map_error_code:3172 ppm_tls_ctr_map_error_code: reason:999 ctr=195
ssl_internal_errors:59 SSL error 999 [error:0A0003E7:SSL routines::invalid session id] ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:tls_process_server_hello:1490:


So, i wanted to debug further by decrypting the Handshake message which are encrypted to get the parameters that my client is sending to server but the callback function set using SSL_CTX_set_keylog_callback is not called after client/server hello post which i get the illegal parameter error.
Could you guys clarify me will the keylog callback function not be called to atleast give me the secrets available till server hello?
How can i decrypt the server hello Application Data and the next packet which is also encrypted?
Please excuse if any of my understanding is wrong.
Thanks,

Your error is not post/after serverhello, it is IN serverhello, and so the client hasn't completed computation of the initial shared secret needed to start the key derivation process (except for resumption/PSK, which this isn't). The parameters your client is sending are in the clienthello unencrypted; you don't need to decrypt anything.

@dave_thompson_085 As shown in the screenshot, the server hello's application data and the next packet from the server are encrypted, any idea if that can be decrypted just to see what server has sent to us ? because i want to find out the illegal parameter sent by server. Please throw some light on this. Thanks

The reason why the callback is not called is that the Server Hello itself had an issue and the openSSL has not calculated any secrets so far.
And the reason for failure is that the client hello sent valid session_id whereas server hello had carried session_id=0 due which the Illegal parameter error was thrown by the client.
As per section 4.1.3 in RFC 8446,  If the client hello had session_id, then the server hello must echo back the session_id.
legacy_session_id_echo:  The contents of the client's
      legacy_session_id field.  Note that this field is echoed even if
      the client's value corresponded to a cached pre-TLS 1.3 session
      which the server has chosen not to resume.  A client which
      receives a legacy_session_id_echo field that does not match what
      it sent in the ClientHello MUST abort the handshake with an
      "illegal_parameter" alert.

Thanks,
Prakash
